# Sending profile settings form developer.org slaesforce to professional salesforce editions

Tags: deployment

Could we send  profile settings form developer.org slaesforce to professional salesforce editions with the help of "packages" and Partner user?. I could send apex triggers is there a way to send profile settings?

Answer (score 1):

You can send complete profiles using tools: [Force.com Migration Tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/) and Eclipse IDE. Even you can try [Salesforce workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) as well.

If you only want to send profile settings. Create an unmanaged package and install it on target org.

Upon installation profile settings will be copied to exact matched profile name.